# [service I created].service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, networking, service, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to set up a website that runs from my computer that runs Ubuntu. I've managed to troubleshoot most of my problems thus far and I think I'm nearing the end of getting this thing online. The website I'm trying to get installed and running is called WriteFreely (it's a minimalist blogging platform that enables myself and others to sign up and start blogging without distractions.

I've followed this guide here: https://writefreely.org/start and have been successful all the way up to the heading **Starting the service**. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and so have followed this instruction: **create a Systemd service by creating a file at /etc/systemd/system/writefreely.service:**. I assumed that I would need to open the text editor, create a .service file called writefreely.service, and copy and paste the service script in:

```
[Unit]
Description=WriteFreely Instance
After=syslog.target network.target
# If MySQL is running on the same machine, uncomment the following 
# line to use it, instead. 
#After=syslog.target network.target mysql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/example.com
ExecStart=/var/www/example.com/writefreely
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In the documentation provided, it tells you to change the /var/www/example.com's to your own domain. I did so by going to /var/www/ and created a folder with my domain in (amcosy.club) and then moved the latest writefreely folder into this newly created folder.

Now, this is where I'm truly unsure what to do. I've entered in `sudo systemctl start writefreely`, it asks for my password and then nothing happens. I assume that's normal. The next input is to verify the application log with `sudo journalctl -f -u writefreely`. This returns the following:

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-04-08 00:01:21 BST. --
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[11537]: writefreely.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[11537]: writefreely.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /var/www/amcosy.club/writefreely: Permission denied
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[1]: writefreely.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[1]: writefreely.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[1]: writefreely.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[1]: writefreely.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[1]: Stopped WriteFreely Instance.
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[1]: writefreely.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[1]: writefreely.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 08 20:10:42 AMCosyClub systemd[1]: Failed to start WriteFreely Instance.
```

I apologise if this is something really obvious but I'm really not great with all this. If I need to provide additional details, please let me know! Very grateful to anyone who can offer insight!

**Edit 1**
Running `id` produces: `uid=1000(harry) gid=1000(harry) groups=1000(harry),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),33(www-data),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare)`

Running `df -h` produces

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  1.9M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda7        41G   27G   13G  70% /
tmpfs           5.9G   64M  5.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop6       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/495
/dev/loop5       49M   49M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
/dev/loop0      161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop7      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/loop4       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
/dev/loop2       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop9      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/135
/dev/loop10     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop11     4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop8       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop12     4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/704
/dev/loop3       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop13      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop14      94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/sda2       256M  110M  147M  43% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.2G   20K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000`

`dmesg` gives a lot feedback. Thousands of lines, actually.

`[   65.595748] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []` is repeated constantly.

`[   65.595754] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: timeout
[   65.595757] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595765] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595815] WARNING: CPU: 4 PID: 294 at /build/linux-hwe-3vURZB/linux-hwe-5.3.0/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/fifo/gk104.c:174 gk104_fifo_runlist_commit+0x140/0x190 [nouveau]
[   65.595816] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595818] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass nouveau snd_hda_codec_hdmi i915 btusb crct10dif_pclmul btrtl crc32_pclmul btbcm mxm_wmi ghash_clmulni_intel ttm btintel
[   65.595824] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595824]  aesni_intel drm_kms_helper bluetooth wl(POE) mei_hdcp aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio xt_hl snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_intel_nhlt ip6t_rt videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_hda_codec
[   65.595832] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595832]  videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common hp_wmi serio_raw videodev snd_hda_core snd_hwdep ecdh_generic sparse_keymap mc input_leds ipt_REJECT ecc wmi_bmof joydev nf_reject_ipv4 snd_pcm drm cfg80211 xt_comment snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops snd_rawmidi syscopyarea rtsx_pci_ms
[   65.595839] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595839]  hp_accel sysfillrect lis3lv02d nf_log_ipv4 sysimgblt memstick input_polldev nf_log_common lpc_ich snd_seq xt_LOG snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore ie31200_edac mac_hid mei_me intel_smartconnect hp_wireless mei
[   65.595847] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595847]  xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype sch_fq_codel xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack parport_pc nf_defrag_ipv6 ppdev nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c iptable_filter bpfilter
[   65.595854] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595855]  lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc r8169 psmouse ahci realtek libahci rtsx_pci wmi video
[   65.595863] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595866] CPU: 4 PID: 294 Comm: kworker/4:2 Tainted: P        W  OE     5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[   65.595867] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP ENVY 17 Notebook PC/1968, BIOS F.60 04/08/2014
[   65.595870] Workqueue: pm pm_runtime_work
[   65.595871] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595908] RIP: 0010:gk104_fifo_runlist_commit+0x140/0x190 [nouveau]
[   65.595909] Code: 45 a8 48 8b 40 10 48 8b 78 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 74 49 e8 62 cc b5 f5 48 89 da 48 89 c6 48 c7 c7 a5 3a 46 c1 e8 10 ce 51 f5 <0f> 0b 41 8b 46 50 85 c0 74 a0 41 8b 46 28 44 89 e9 48 c7 c6 b0 8a
[   65.595910] RSP: 0018:ffffac5b803f7a80 EFLAGS: 00010282
[   65.595912] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9fa810bf8450 RCX: 0000000000000006
[   65.595912] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: ffff9fa813117440
[   65.595913] RBP: ffffac5b803f7ae0 R08: 000000000057c9a3 R09: 0000000000000004
[   65.595914] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 00000000000022a4
[   65.595915] R13: 0000000000000004 R14: ffff9fa80df1a000 R15: 0000000000000000
[   65.595915] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595917] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9fa813100000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   65.595918] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   65.595919] CR2: 00007f9f1d3e1120 CR3: 000000029500a002 CR4: 00000000001606e0
[   65.595920] Call Trace:
[   65.595922] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595958]  gk104_fifo_runlist_update+0x1cc/0x200 [nouveau]
[   65.595959] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.595994]  gk104_fifo_gpfifo_fini+0x84/0xa0 [nouveau]
[   65.595994] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596030]  nvkm_fifo_chan_fini+0x1d/0x30 [nouveau]
[   65.596030] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596047]  nvkm_object_fini+0xbd/0x220 [nouveau]
[   65.596048] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596066]  nvkm_object_fini+0x78/0x220 [nouveau]
[   65.596067] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596088]  nvkm_object_fini+0x78/0x220 [nouveau]
[   65.596089] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596104]  nvkm_object_fini+0x78/0x220 [nouveau]
[   65.596105] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596136]  nvkm_client_suspend+0x13/0x20 [nouveau]
[   65.596136] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596156]  nvif_client_suspend+0x1d/0x20 [nouveau]
[   65.596157] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596185]  nouveau_do_suspend+0x1a0/0x2c0 [nouveau]
[   65.596186] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596215]  nouveau_pmops_runtime_suspend+0x44/0xb0 [nouveau]
[   65.596215] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596218]  pci_pm_runtime_suspend+0x62/0x1a0
[   65.596222]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
[   65.596222] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596224]  ? pci_pm_runtime_resume+0xd0/0xd0
[   65.596227]  __rpm_callback+0x9b/0x150
[   65.596228]  ? pci_pm_runtime_resume+0xd0/0xd0
[   65.596230]  rpm_callback+0x24/0x80
[   65.596231] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596233]  rpm_suspend+0x109/0x600
[   65.596236]  ? __switch_to+0x85/0x480
[   65.596237]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
[   65.596238]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
[   65.596239] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596241]  pm_runtime_work+0x78/0xa0
[   65.596244]  process_one_work+0x1fd/0x3f0
[   65.596246]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
[   65.596248]  kthread+0x121/0x140
[   65.596248] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596251]  ? process_one_work+0x3f0/0x3f0
[   65.596252]  ? kthread_park+0xb0/0xb0
[   65.596254]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[   65.596255] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596256] ---[ end trace 4dbe70ab8c0632f5 ]---
[   65.596258] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: runlist 4 update timeout
[   65.596263] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596273] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[   65.596283] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 []
[  126.942326] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp8s0 OUT= MAC=(MAC Address) df:(df) SRC=(SRC) DST=(DST) LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2`

**Edit 2**
After running `sudo ls -l /var/www/amcosy.club/writefreely` I get the following:

`total 50600
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     1004 Apr  7 20:43 config.ini
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     4096 Apr  7 20:43 keys
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     4096 Dec 18 02:41 pages
drwxrwxrwx 6 root root     4096 Dec 18 02:41 static
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root     4096 Dec 18 02:41 templates
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51786256 Dec 18 02:43 writefreely`

Answer (score 1):

Just installed writefreely on an Ubuntu 18.04 test machine following your guide without problem:

```
$ sudo journalctl  -u writefreely
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-04-09 20:43:07 UTC, end at Thu 2020-04-09 21:57:13 UTC. --
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started WriteFreely Instance.
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Starting WriteFreely 0.11.2...
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Loading config.ini configuration...
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Loading templates...
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Loading pages...
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Loading user pages...
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Loading encryption keys...
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Connecting to sqlite3 database...
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Adding {domain} routes (single user)...
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Going to serve...
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 Serving on http://localhost:8080
Apr 09 21:57:00 ubuntu writefreely[1435]: 2020/04/09 21:57:00 ---
```

Probably you have some other problem on your host.

Comment: Hi @rgio, thank you so much for offering advice! Running yhr ls -dl /var/... command returns the following: drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Apr  8 14:40 /var/www/amcosy.club. However, I still get the same error when running sudo journalctl -f -u writefreely. Am I missing a command? Sorry for the noob questions :)

Comment: Hi what's the output of ls -l /var/www/amocsy.club/writefreely ?

Comment: when trying to run -l /var/www/amcosy.club/writefreely I get: `-l: command not found`

Comment: Actually is 
   `ls -l /var/www/amocsy.club/writefreely`

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/var/www/amcosy.club/writefreely/writefreely': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/var/www/amcosy.club/writefreely/static': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/var/www/amcosy.club/writefreely/keys': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/var/www/amcosy.club/writefreely/config.ini': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/var/www/amcosy.club/writefreely/pages': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/var/www/amcosy.club/writefreely/templates': Permission denied`

Comment: `total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? config.ini
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? keys
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? pages
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? static
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? templates
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? writefreely`

Comment: had to put output over two comments because of character limit ^^ sorry!

Comment: What user are you? Please print the result of `id` command.

Comment: You got all those `?`? Seems you have problem on your filesystem. You can check with `df -h` and `dmesg` command

Comment: HI @rgio, I have updated my original post with information from the commands you suggested. It looks like a lot has gone wrong, would a clean install be better?

Comment: Hi @H412 I edited my answer, can you check? If it still not works, then can you print me output of `sudo ls -l /var/www/amocsy.club/writefreely`?

Comment: HI @rgio, tried what your edited answer says and still no luck. I have put the output from sudo ls -l in the edited question :)